# Draw SQL statement evaluation plan (tree)

Tags: sql, database, charts, relational-database, draw

I would like to draw a SQL evaluation plan, e.g. a tree where the leafs show that the result set is filtered with the given arguments and then the broad result set is reduced by only projecting relevent attributes and then at last the join happens with the smallest possible result set of both sets.

There is some algebraic language to this, but I can't find any nice tool to get it in a tree form.

Comment: Graphviz can produce such layouts. See [this][1] other question here on SO


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2271704/family-tree-layout-with-dot-graphviz

Comment: I just looked at the examples, but I can't see any special relational algebra notation. Are you sure it can do that?

Comment: I do not know if this is may help you http://dotnetprof.blogspot.com/2013/07/draw-hierarchical-tree-in-html-using.html