# Forcing orthogonal (vertical or horizontal) edges with dot

Tags: graphviz, dot, edges, orthogonal

I would like to force dot displaying only vertical or horizontal edges between nodes.

I have found a similar request with the post [Family tree layout with Dot/GraphViz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2271704/family-tree-layout-with-dot-graphviz), but I am not dealing with trees, so I hope there is a solution without inserting extra nodes...

If I build the following graph:

```
digraph G {

    splines=ortho

    A [ shape=box ]
    B [ shape=box ]
    C [ shape=box ]
    D [ shape=box ]

    A -> B
    A -> C

    B -> D
    C -> D

}
```

What I get is this:

[image]

But I would like a graph like this one:

[image]

How can I get such a rendering ?

Edit : the "splines" attribute seems not working as expected... Is there something I did wrong ?

Answer (score 46):

Your syntax seems correct. When I run it I get orthogonal edge routing (of sorts):

[image]

Which version do you have?

I ask because orthogonal edge routing is only available in Graphviz versions from September 28, 2010 and newer. Not all systems have more recent versions packed. On my system I had to [download](http://www.graphviz.org/Download..php) and manually install Graphviz to get a version newer than 2.26.3 (which is from January 26, 2010).

Assuming your actual graph contains more than 4 nodes, if you want the lines to have a bend and you don't want to add extra (invisible) nodes, you should try playing around with the 
graphs `nodesep` attribute. See code and image below.

```
digraph G {

    graph [splines=ortho, nodesep=1]
    node [shape=record]

    A -> {B, C} -> D
}
```

[image]

Comment: I am using graphviz 3.2.1 and 'ortho' isn't working for me either :(. It looks just like shortest straight lines between nodes.